# Android. TabWidget always on top for now?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, tabwidget, android-fragmentactivity

I'm studying working with tabs using fragments. And I'm wondering how can I place TabWidget in the bottom of page.

I'm looking into FragmentTab.java sample (support library v4).

There is a XML layout:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And whatever I do TabWidget is still on top. Actually I can remove TabWidget tag at all and still the project would be successfully launched and the TabWidget would be on top again.

Does it mean for now using FragmentActivity and FragmentTabHost I can only get my TabWidget on top?

Thank you.

Comment: u got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! I think what is missing here is you are putting `TabWidget` **before** `FrameLayout`. Also I don't think you can't set 0dp width and height to your `@android:id/tabcontent`, it is the one that needs to be visible and have `layout_weight="1"`. Try this (edited):

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
       <!--
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
       -->
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: Yeah, I tryed doing this, but it didnt help. I even removed TabWidget tag at all, and still tab widget was at the bottom...

Comment: Then the problem is what I thought... `realtabcontent` can't be your visible FrameLayout, `tabcontent` is the one that needs to have those properties. See the update.

Comment: Sorry Sergio, but It didn't help again. May be my sdk requirements do this. I have minSdkVersion="9" and targetSdkVersion="15"...